# How to allow mysql remote connections via particular interface

Tags: firewall, ip, mysql

I have a `10.237.49.251` IP on `eth0` and another IP on another interface

How do I enable remote mysql calls on `eth0` device?

Comment: Do you mean you want the MySQL server to listen only on a particular interface? Or do you want a MySQL client to choose a particular route to a remote server?

Answer (score 18):

The mysqld configuration file - at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on my Linux box - has a `bind-address` option. This can be set to a particular IP address, like 10.237.49.251, and MySQL will then *only* listen on that interface (eth0).

The default (at least on Ubuntu) is to listen only on localhost, aka. the loopback interface (127.0.0.1).

Otherwise, MySQL can listen on all available ports and interfaces, which can be explicitly specified with `bind-address=0.0.0.0` in the `[mysqld]` section.

Answer (score 4):

you can use :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -d 10.237.49.251 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

For wsl

sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

add

bind-address = 0.0.0.0 under [mysqld] section

Comment: Beyond hard-coding an editor, I don't see how this adds anything beyond [Alex Leach's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52152/117549)

Comment: This is for wsl specific

Comment: It sounds like the same answer works in WSL, which is great -- but also means, that you should simply upvote Alex's answer instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: The file path is different

Comment: Ahhh, then perhaps this answer would be better suited to a WSL question, since there's no indication in this question that WSL is in use?